# How can I query a T-SQL table in limited rows at a time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, grouping, query-performance

I have a table with (eg) 1500 rows. I have determined that (due to the resources of the server) my query can quickly process up to 500 rows of my table in my desired query. Any more than 500 rows at once and it suddenly becomes very slow.

How can I structure a query to process the contents of a table in row groups of 500, through to the end of the table?

**[EDIT]** The query which takes a long time is this:

```
select p.childid, max(c.childtime) ChildTime
from child c
    inner join @parents p on p.parentid = c.parentid
        and c.ChildTypeID = 1
    AND c.childtime < getdate()
group by p.parentid
```

The problem is that the `point` table has millions of rows and (for reasons I can't go into here) can't be reduced.

The main problem is: reducing the number of rows from the child table to make the query performant. Unfortunately, this query is being performed to populate a temporary table so that a subsequent query can execute quickly.

Comment: Use Top 500 in select query?

Comment: I would look into fixing whatever is causing your query to run slowly rather than trying to circumvent the issue. 1500 rows is absolutely nothing, whatever query you have should run fast enough against it.

Comment: It's being joined to a rather large query with MAX() and various other things. The execution plan shows not much which can be improved, tbh. TOP 500 would not help because it won't process the remaining rows. I just want to process 500 at a time, until the end of the table. Surely that's possible, no?

Comment: What sort of processing are you talking about?

Comment: Depends on your data. Basically you want pagination. e.g something like where line_number between page_start and page_start + 499. Next time thru page_start is the last ones, page end.

Comment: The processing I'm talking about is the processing that the server performs when you execute a SQL query. I guess I am asking about pagination, I just can't figure out how to get it to do that. Essentially, executing a query which joins no more than 500 rows on this one table runs fine. So I want to break that into blocks of 500 without having to use a loop or execute separate statements.

Comment: If there really is nothing you can do to optimize the query, I'd say you should look into perhaps some sql jobs that pre-process some of the data for you. For example have a job which each day which pre-calculates the report for you so you can call that result table instead of making the report/query on demand - or look into indexed views or partitioning of your data so you can limit the number of data that the query has to go through. I wouldn't recommend window functions to solve the problem, but perhaps some subqueries into another table (sort of cache) can help as well.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the windowing functions. Only trick is that they cannot be used in the WHERE clause, so you will have to use subqueries.

```
Select a.*, b.*
From 
 (
  Select *, rownum = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by fieldx)
  From TableA
  ) a
  Inner Join TableB b on a.fieldx=b.fieldx
Where a.rownum between @startnum and @endnum
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for processing you might be able to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @RowsPerPage INT = 500, @PageNumber INT = 1
DECLARE @TotalRows INT

SET @TotalRows = (SELECT count(1) from test)

WHILE (@RowsPerPage * @PageNumber < @TotalRows)
BEGIN

    SELECT
        Id
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT
                Id,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) as RowNum
            FROM Test
        ) AS sub
    WHERE sub.RowNum BETWEEN ((@PageNumber-1)*@RowsPerPage)+1
        AND @RowsPerPage*(@PageNumber)

    SET @PageNumber = @PageNumber + 1

END
```

Calculates the total rows and then loops and pages through the results. It's not too helpful if you need your results together, though, because this will run X number of separate queries. You might be able to put this in a stored procedure and union the results or something crazy like that to get the results in one "query".

I still think a better option would be to fix the slowness in your original query. Is it possible to load the join results into a CTE/Temp table to only perform calculations a single time? If you could give an example of your query that would help a lot...